# how to avoid re-inserting data into sql table while re-running SSIS package that loads data from flat file to SQL table?

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have a flat file with the following data

```
Id,FirstName,LastName,Address,PhoneNumber
1,ben,afflick,xyz Address,5014123746
3,christina,smith,test address,111000110
1,ben,afflick,xyz Address,5014123746
3,christina,smith,test address,111000110
4,nash,gordon,charlotte NC ADDRESS,111200110
```

I have created a SSIS package that has flat file source , and an aggregate function that makes sure that only unique rows are inserted and not duplicate records from the flat file , and SQL table as my destination.

Everything is fine when i run the package , i am getting below output in SQL table

```
Id  FName   LName   Address phoneNumber
1   ben afflick xyz Address 5014123746
4   nash    gordon  charlotte NC ADDRESS    111200110
3   christina   smith   test address    111000110
```

But when i add some new data to the flat file as below

```
Id,FirstName,LastName,Address,PhoneNumber
1,ben,afflick,xyz Address,5014123746
3,christina,smith,test address,111000110
1,ben,afflick,xyz Address,5014123746
3,christina,smith,test address,111000110
4,nash,gordon,charlotte NC ADDRESS,111200110
5,abc,xyz,New York,9999988888
```

and re-run the package the data that is already present in the table is getting re-inserted as below

```
1   ben afflick xyz Address 5014123746
4   nash    gordon  charlotte NC ADDRESS    111200110
3   christina   smith   test address    111000110
1   ben afflick xyz Address 5014123746
5   abc xyz New York    9999988888
4   nash    gordon  charlotte NC ADDRESS    111200110
3   christina   smith   test address    111000110
```

But i DO NOT want this , i don't want data to be inserted that is already present.
I want only the newly added data to get inserted into the SQL table.

Can someone please help me to achieve this?

Comment: you can do a look up with the base table against the key attributes and insert only non matched records

Comment: Based on your sample data, the first column is a unique identifer. Is this always the case?

Comment: yes first column is always unique

Answer (score 1):

Your data flow task would look something like this. Here, the Flat file source reads the CSV file and then passes the data to Lookup transformation. This transformation will check for existing data in the destination table.  If there are no matching records, then the data from CSV file will be sent to the OLE DB Destination otherwise, the data will be discarded only.
lookup Transformation link ---

[http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/574437/Term-Lookup-Transformation-in-SSIS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GT7I9.png)

[image: sort and lookup transformation in ssis]

Comment: and what about the duplicate rows that are already present in my flat file how do i remove them?

Comment: @archanaSriram in case of removing duplicate you need to use Sort transformation of SSIS .
http://www.msbiguide.com/2012/11/sort-transformation-in-ssis-with-example/

Comment: im new to ssis , i have been learning it through videos n posts online , how do i use sort and lookup together?

Comment: @archanaSriram you first need to add sort transformation then add lookup. for your reference I have attached a image in my answer .

Answer (score 1):

Another method is to load your file into a staging table in the database and then use a merge statement to insert data into your destination table.

In practice this would look like a data flow from your flat file to your staging table and then a execute sql task containing a merge statement.
You can then update any matching values as well, should you wish to.

```
merge into table_a 
using stage_a
on stage_a.key = table_a.key
when not matched then insert (a,b,c,d) values ( a,b,c,d )
```